# SQL function - Returning value for number of records in table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function

I am putting a bit of SQL into an Oracle script, if I run the Vanilla SQL i get the correct output of one single returned value/record. However in my custom function I get the value I am looking for returned as many times as there are records. Here is an example of what I  have.

```
create function EXAMPLE_FUNCTION (passedID in NUMBER)
return NUMBER
IS 
returnValue NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT "TABLE1"."ID" INTO returnValue
FROM "TABLE1" WHERE "TABLE1"."ID" = passedID;
RETURN  returnValue;
END;
```

So if TABLE1 has 20 records I will get the record with ID 1 returned 20 times,
I am not sure where its going wrong, but I'm sure its simple!

Comment: Can you further clarify what you are wanting to do?  What result are you expecting?  How are you calling this function?

Comment: If you're getting 20 return values, you must be calling the function 20 times.  Show us how you are calling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably calling the function like this:

```
select EXAMPLE_FUNCTION (1)
from my_table
```

Call it without the from:

```
select EXAMPLE_FUNCTION (1)
```

EDIT:

As pointed by Shannon Oracle requires the from clause so I searched and found examples using the `dual` table:

```
select EXAMPLE_FUNCTION (1)
from dual
```

Comment: This makes lots of sense, however without the from I get "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: -1 Oracle always requires a from clause for a select statement.

Comment: Edited with a hint from searches

Comment: Per edit, removed down vote. @Beck: About the dual table see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036

Answer (score 2):

Just do something like: SELECT EXAMPLE_FUNCTION(1) FROM dual;

Answer (score 1):

Would something like the below work in your function?

```
Select COUNT(*) into returnValue 
from TABLE1 
where Table1.ID = passedID;
```

Comment: It runs but I get the same 'problem', I am fairly certain Kakao is right.

Comment: Oh, the way you call it you got 20 entries, not that the inside of the function has 20 return values. I didn't understand the question.  This code would make the function easier to understand, and Kakao's way of calling it will give you the answer once.

Answer (score 1):

What value are you using for `passedID?`  If you want to get soemthing different out for each row you need to pass something different in.

Compare these two function calls.  First a fixed value:

```
SQL> select example_function(1) from table1
  2  /

EXAMPLE_FUNCTION(1)
-------------------
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1
                  1

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Then using the table column to supply the parameter:

```
SQL> select example_function(id) from table1
  2  /

EXAMPLE_FUNCTION(ID)
--------------------
                   1
                   2
                   3
                   4
                   5
                   6
                   7
                   8
                   9
                  10
                  11
                  12
                  13
                  14
                  15
                  16
                  17
                  18
                  19
                  20

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```